4k aliasing and the reissued load
With 4K aliasing, the last 12 bits of the address are used to determine if for a load there is a match in the store buffer. Which can lead to false matches and the load being reissued in case of a false match.
My question is what exactly happens when the load is reissued. Could it happens that there is a continuous cycle of reissued loads until the store has been drained from the store buffer?

AFAIK, the replay mechanism is used to optimistically send an instruction X that depends on on instruction Y to the EU while Y is still executing/is being dispatched. So I think it's a different mechanism that the 4k aliasing. The latter allows a load to skip other stores in the SB and get the data from that. If the prediction is wrong, the pipe is nuked. The replay would allow a back to back aliasing store and load to be dispatched on the same cycle. I'm not sure, though.

I don't think so for this case as Margaret says.  But for normal cache-miss loads, Intel CPUs re-dispatch (from the scheduler to an execution unit, in Intel terminology) uops dependent on the load, optimistically anticipating the arrival of data from L1 hit, then L2 hit, then repeatedly after that.  Why does the number of uops per iteration increase with the stride of streaming loads? / About the RIDL vulnerabilities and the "replaying" of loads.  (The load itself doesn't have to get replayed.)
